# closing dropdown by clicking outside

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to close my dropdown menu not only by clicking the x, but by clicking outside of it aswell. My js code doesnt seem to work. The Javascript is copied from a template i had left somewhere but im actually not able to fix it in order for it to work.

```js
window.onclick = function closeMenu() {
  if(document.getElementById("dropdown-content").style.left != "-300px") {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdown[i];
      if(openDropdown.style.left != ('-300px')) {
        openDropdown.style.left = ('-300px');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
  z-index: 600;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#dropdown-content {
  left: -300px;
  z-index: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
    <div class="menubutton" onclick="menu(this)">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menulist">
      <a href="#">Angebot des Tages</a>
      <a href="#">Alle Angebote</a>
      <a href="#">Technik</a>
      <a href="#">Hardware</a>
      <a href="#">Mode</a>
      <a href="#">Automobil</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Checking styles like that is a fragile way to go about things--if your theme styles change you have to update your script. You should be using CSS classes, possibly on the body element or some other ancestor.

Comment: Please provide HTML so we can reproduce.

Comment: Have you heard of `<select>` with `<option>`s?

Comment: The "drop-down" is off-screen...

Comment: It's not designed for this but you could do: https://jsfiddle.net/ycz5p4wg/

Answer (score 1):

```js
const x = document.querySelector('.x');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

x.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ul.classList.toggle('show');
});

document.addEventListener('click', ({
  target
}) => {
  if (target.matches('.x') === false) {
    ul.classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">X</div>
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Here, we track the `X` and just use `toggle()`, for any other click we ensure it is not `X` and then just `remove()` our show class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just vanilla javascript, you can add a `eventListener` to the `document` object that listens to `click` event and checking some condition of the dropdown to check if it's opened, if it is, then closes it, if it's not, do nothing.

Something like:

```
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const dropdown = ... // grab dropdown element
  if (isOpened(dropdown)) closeDropdown()
})
```

EDIT: Also you should check if the click happened outside your dropdown since it will also be triggered if it is clicked. For that you can use the [Node API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains).

Leaving it as:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const dropdown = ... // grab dropdown element
  if (dropdown.contains(e.target)) return; // if the clicked element is inside the dropdown or it's the dropdown itself, do nothing
  if (isOpened(dropdown)) closeDropdown()
})
```

Comment: Oh yesss! Missed that you should check that the click is outside your dropdown menu, editing my comment in a few

Comment: don't know if im doing something extremly wrong but im right if i replace the ... with my document.getElementById("dropdown-content") arent I? Unfortunately the dropdown menu isn't openable with that code so far.

Comment: No, that code will only just close the dropdown if anything apart of the dropdown is clicked. But it doesn't do anything with openning the dropdown, that is another question

Comment: Yes i see that but im still using the original code i posted in order to open the menu which doesnt work anymore.

Comment: I don't know how to help you there since it's totally other question. I would recommend you to append a class or something to the dropdown when it's opened as its widely-used and easier to check. Try to not rely in styling of the element since if the styling changes it will break everything. Please mark the answer as correct if it is suitable :)

Comment: Nevermind the problem is a missing bracket. I have to add it at the very end right?

Comment: Oh yeah, the parenthesis. Editing my answer

Comment: Great now the menu is opening but still not closing by clicking outside of it

Comment: Try console logging the dropdown element and the `e.target` inside the `eventListener`, any of both would be the problem

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you to solve the problem :)